# Where is the firebase session stocked in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I was wondering since I don't find the answer online, where or "how" is the firebase user session (using `auth()`) stocked in React Native ?

I know it's open source but I can't find what I want. If possible I would like to know the location/way for both ios and android.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the firebase session" (Firebase has 18+ products by now) and what "stocked" means?

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear. I'm talking about Authentication and the user data that you can call like `auth().currentUser?.email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In browser based environments, Firebase Authentication stores the user credentials in local storage, and restores them from there when the page reloads.

In native Android environments, Firebase Authentication stores the user credentials in the shared preferences of the app, and restore them from there when the app reloads.

In native iOS environments, Firebase Authentication stores the user credentials in the user's keychain, and restore them from there when the app reloads.

If you need to control the storage of the user credentials in a JavaScript environment, check the documentation on [auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) to learn about your options.